# Outputting data from another file

Tags: python

So I am trying to gather data from another file called 'setup.txt'. The data I am trying to grab is from any line in the file that starts with "Subject:", I will grab the value following it (for example, **r39770**).

So here is an example of a line in 'setup.txt' :
Subject: [sakai] svn commit: **r39770** - site-manage/branches/sakai_2-5-x/site-manage-tool/tool/src/webapp/vm/sitesetup

All I want to do is extract **r39770** and output it to a .csv file.

Here is my code:

```
with open(file_name) as file:
   for line in file:
      if line.startswith("Subject:"):
         subject = line.split()[1]
         subjects.append(subject)
return subjects
```

And the output I get is [sakai] instead of what I am trying to get.

Comment: Please post the full error message as text

Comment: Seems like you're getting what you coded... What _are_ you trying to get?

Comment: Your `split` is breaking the line by the spaces and grabbing the second word, which in your case is the `[sakai]`. If you know that your desired output is always the 5th word, you could use `line.split()[4]`. We need to know more about what pattern you are expecting to see.

Comment: Is there a specific pattern in the lines you are processing, or the codes you are trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

if you can guarantee that the line that start with subject will always contain the same amount of words, with the desired code always in that position, just change split()[1] to split()[4] and you are done. End of answer

But, if you know any kind of pattern between the codes, then its definitely better to use Regex in this case. Something like

```
import re
with open(file_name) as file:
   for line in file:
      if line.startswith("Subject:"):
         match = re.search(r'\s[a-z]\d+\s', line)
         if match is not None:
             subjects.append(match.group().strip())
         else:
             # handle the case where you didn't find the code with your pattern
return subjects
```

This pattern would find this specific case (a word separated by spaces that contains a single lowercase letter followed but any amount of numbers) but of course you need to change it to get all of them. The advantage is that you can more reliably find the sequence, and handle the cases where you couldn't.

https://regex101.com/ --> this is the best site to help build regex patterns